# Signalr Method silently fails because can't serialize when custom constructor added to model

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have a model that can be passed as an argument on hub methods.

```
public class Card {
  public int Color;
  public int Number;
  public Card HelperCard;

  public Card(int color, int number) {
    Color = color;
    Number = number;
  }

  // second constructor
  public Card(int color, int number, bool isHelper) {
    if (isHelper) {
       HelperCard = new Card(color, number);
    }
  }
}
```

If I add the *second constructor* the hub methods silently failing, when I remove it it works fine.

Comment: Without seeing your hub method, I am wondering if you are passing in false as the argument to isHelper, and then trying to access HelperCard, which I believe would be null. Are you using try catch in the hub method? Logging exceptions?

Comment: the hub method is never called, and there is nothing special about it, it just takes a Card as an argument. @spojam